# PL/SQL Stored Procedure in Oracle Application Express not running

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created the stored procedure which compiled with no errors. But when I run **exec sp_DATE_D(2005, 2006);** I receive the following error: 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "SP_DATE_D", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1

I expect my sample data to look like this as an example of one row:
DATE_KEY: 01/01/2005 
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION: Monday, January 1, 2005

The procedure should populate from this point up until the last day of the 2nd parameter.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_DD(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');

DELETE FROM DATE_D;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP
INSERT INTO DATE_D
(
    DATE_KEY, 
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION
)   
VALUES
(
    TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY'),
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY')
);
v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_D
(  
    DATE_KEY DATE NOT NULL,
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DATE_DIMENSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY)
);
```

To add:
Can't figure how out if its a format issue or I should convert.

**Solution:**

Modified Line 22 -

```
v_CURRENT_DATE,
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include the definition of table DATE_D. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis I started out with a small table which I plan to expand to add weeks and days and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be this line:

```
TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY'),
```

`v_CURRENT_DATE` is already a DATE variable. To pass it to the TO_DATE function Oracle has to convert it to a string, and the default string format for dates is `DD-MON-RR`. So if `v_CURRENT_DATE` already contains 1-JAN-2005, this is converted to the string '01-JAN-05', which is then passed to TO_DATE. But the format argument being passed to TO_DATE is `'MMDDYYYY'`, which doesn't match the string it's being handed ('01-JAN-05'), and so the TO_DATE function fails.

The solution is fairly simple: since `v_CURRENT_DATE` is already a DATE variable there's no need to call TO_DATE at all. Change the INSERT statement to:

```
INSERT INTO DATE_D
(
    DATE_KEY, 
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION
)   
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY')
);
```

Comment: So if at anytime I want to see the v_CURRENT_DATE in a different format, I need to use the TO_CHAR function ? When I run a select * on the data I just inserted, why would the DATE_KEY field show as MM/DD/YYYY and not the default DD-MON-YY ?

Comment: It looks like the command line shows the default, whereas the data in Application Express shows a different format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Comment: Application Express may have a setting which controls how it displays dates. I don't have Application Express, but I know that PL/SQL Developer has a setting like that.